# Retrieving single parts of a javasript/jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi suppose I have a jQuery selector such as this:

```
var a = $(this);
var b = a.nextUntil("button").text();
```

This will retrieve all the DOM elements till the next button. I want to access all these DOM elements individually as separate objects. Is there  way to do that?

Comment: Yes, use a loop: https://api.jquery.com/each

Comment: Note that by adding `text()` after the collection all you have is a single string of all text from all elements in that collection ....Try `a.nextUntil("button").each(function(){ console.log($(this).text()) })`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute a function for each of the elements, you can use [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

If you want all the objects to be in an array, you can do something like this:

```
var arr = a.nextUntil("button")
```

and then index it as an array.

```
console.log($(a[0]).text())
```

Comment: jQuery already creates an array of the elements. Creating a new array `arr` seems redundant and pointless

Comment: Also there is no explicit `this` in an arrow function so your code isn't doing what you think it is